# Slowdows during a delete and a read on the same table from different stored procedures in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

In the project I'm working on, we have detected some slowdowns during the execution of two stored procedures (sp).
More precisely, it happens when both try to run some statements on the same table in the nearly same moment.
The two statements are:

- delete a single row from the table (this happens in the sp A)
- make an update on a temporary table which is in join with the deleting table in the sp A (this happens in the sp B)

When these slowdonws happens, it can also take some minutes for the statements to terminate.

The fields used for the join and also for the delete where clause are indexed, but no-one of these is the clustered index, it's on another field.

Here is an example of the code:

SP A

```
...other code...
DELETE OrderItems
OUTPUT @LogId, DELETE.OrderId, ...[Other colums]
INTO OrderItemsLog( LogId, OrderId, ...[Other columns] )
WHERE OrderId = @OrderId
...other code...
```

SP B

```
...other code...
UPDATE [Update some columns on the temp table]
FROM #TempOrderItems toi
    JOIN OrderItems oi ON toi.OrderId = oi.OrderId AND toi.OrderItemId = oi.OrderItemId
...other code...
```

When these two statements are executed in the nearly same moment, there are slowdowns.

Does anyone know what it might be the reason...?

Tnx

Comment: You need to check what's going on in the database, blocking, query plans, deadlocks etc. when the slowdown happens. Just based on reading the code you can't do much.

Answer (score 0):

I would try and gather this following info:
Blocking & Wait Info from sys.sysprocesses.
Deadlocks: If lucky (if your DBAs allow) try DBCC TRACEON (1204, 1222) then you will see Deadlocks in the SQL Log
sys.dm_tran_locks - You might see some Lock Escalation happening - Eg If SQL decides to Lock a Page or Higher when you run your delete. 
Best if you can have these outputting every 10 secs or so so you can see what happens over time (Foglight or a tool like this would defo help)